# How can we go to chat profile of user from main site profile?

Tags: support, chat, profile-page

When I click on a user's name or gravatar in the chat interface, I get a popup with a number of options like:

- user profile
- user profile on (chat user's parent site)

Like from which we can go to user's profile on main site. So I was thinking is there any link given on main site for chat user's profile. I have searched it but didn't got any.

If this option is present currently how can I do?

Comment: You can search for chat users here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users